# Как в vue.js роутере сделать ссылку на api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Использую стандартный пакет vue с webpack из коробки, но не могу обработать определённые api пути. Нужно, что б  по этим путям запускался код node.js, а по всем остальным vue single page application с роутером, как и в базовых примерах.

Comment: эта задача решается на уровне сервера. Vue-router тут не причем

Comment: @Дмытрык ну я понял, только как настроить это, что б сперва срабатывал мой апи роутер и потом, если это не апи, то перекидывал бы на приложение vue?

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: @Дмытрык  у меня к серверу идёт запрос по адресу server.com/api/command - мне нужно здесь выдать не html vue файл, а ответ- например "1"

Comment: выведите в отдельный модуль опции роутера, там где Вы пути указываете - и используйте его как на фронте, так и на сервере. На сервере проверяйте - если путь есть в этом файле - значит Html, если нет - значит "1"